# MySQL design regarding a web

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am tackling a problem in class to design a mySQL representation of a web that stores a list of events associated with a person. So, for this table/tables, it would have 2 columns, one of which is the person's name and the other is the event. However, a person will generally have anywhere from 30-1000 events, so this table, which we plan to have for our entire undergraduate class of 6000 students, will have millions of entries. Is there a better way to store this in mySQL that will take **less space**, but will still be able to retrieve individual events and the list of people that attended it just as easily as if it was a table of two columns?

Comment: What do you mean by a "web"? Are you referring to a website? Or an interrelated series of data points?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a technique called *many-to-many*, and essentially breaks your one table into three, which is critical when you consider that there are indeed exactly three entities being modeled (as a good sanity check)

1. Person
2. Event
3. A Person's association with an Event

You model this as three tables, with the first two having essentially two columns each: one with a unique index (called "primary key"), and the second being a semantic name (person name, event name). Note that you can also add any number of columns to these with only one factor of increased storage (most likely your first move will be to add a date column to the event table).

The third table is the interesting one, it contains only 2 columns, each numeric, both of which are references to the other tables (each row is simply: (person_id, event_id)). We term these "foreign keys".

This structure means a few things:

1. No matter how many events someone goest to, that someone is only represented once.
2. same with events, not matter how many attendees
3. The attendance is a "first-class" entity, and can grow to include it's own attributes (i.e. "role")

This structure is called many-to-many because each person may attend many events, and each event may have many attendees.

The quintessential feature of the design is that no single piece of domain knowledge is repeated, only "keys" are repeated as necessary to model the real-world domain. (i.e. in your first example, accounting for a name change would require an unknown quantity of updates, and might lead to data anomalies, avoidance of which is a primary concern of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about "space". This isn't the 1970s and we're not going to run out of columns on punch cards to store data. You should be concerned with expressing your requirements in the proper, most *normalized* data structure. With proper indexing there shouldn't be a problem, not with this volume of data.

Remember indexes need to be defined on anything you will include as part of a `WHERE` clause, and sometimes you may need to add additional indexes for large lists fetched with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

Whenever possible or practical use an integer identifier instead of a string. These are stored as a small number of bytes, typically 4, compared with a variable length string which is typically at least the length of the string in bytes plus 1.

A properly normalized database will use numerical identifiers for things anyway, so this kind if thing isn't a huge concern. The only time you go against this, or deliberately de-normalize your data, is when you have a legitimate performance problem that cannot be easily solved using some other method.

As always, test your schema by generating large amounts of dummy data and see how it performs. Since you have a good idea of the requirements in advance, do some testing at those levels, and then, to be on the safe side, try 2x, 5x and 10x the data to see how much flexibility your design has. It's okay to have performance limitations so long as you know at what kind of scale you'll experience them.

Answer (score 0):

mySQL relational databases were designed specifically to handle this sort of problem.  Handling millions of entries is not a problem.  Complex queries may take a couple seconds but will perform remarkably well.

It is best design to store 1 event per row.  The way you are going about it sounds like the best way.  Good Luck.